# Migrate Elasticsearch index to Kubernetes with synonym and stop words files

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

We have an ElasticSearch cluster deployed on VMs, and we want to migrate it to Kubernetes. In the meantime, I realized that one of our indexes has a lot of files for synonyms and stopwords. You can see the setting in the following list:

```
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "routing" : {
      "allocation" : {
        "include" : {
          "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
        }
      }
    },
    "mapping" : {
      "ignore_malformed" : "true"
    },
    "refresh_interval" : "30s",
    "number_of_shards" : "3",
    "provided_name" : "ecommerce-aug-14",
    "max_inner_result_window" : "200",
    "default_pipeline" : "ecommerce-pipeline",
    "creation_date" : "1692020601428",
    "analysis" : {
      "filter" : {
        "condition_shingle_filter" : {
          "filter" : [
            "shingle_filter"
          ],
          "type" : "condition",
          "script" : {
            "source" : """ !token.type.contains( "SYNONYM") """
          }
        },
        "graph_synonyms" : {
          "updateable" : "false",
          "type" : "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt",
          "lenient" : "true"
        },
        "limit_2_token" : {
          "type" : "limit",
          "max_token_count" : "2"
        },
        "alphabet_num_sep" : {
          "catenate_all" : "true",
          "split_on_case_change" : "false",
          "type" : "word_delimiter_graph",
          "preserve_original" : "true"
        },
        "shingle_filter" : {
          "token_separator" : "",
          "type" : "shingle"
        },
        "limit_3_token" : {
          "type" : "limit",
          "max_token_count" : "3"
        },
        "graph_synonyms3gram" : {
          "updateable" : "false",
          "type" : "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym3gram.txt",
          "lenient" : "true"
        },
        "graph_synonyms2gram" : {
          "updateable" : "false",
          "type" : "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym2gram.txt",
          "lenient" : "true"
        },
        "limit_1_token" : {
          "type" : "limit",
          "max_token_count" : "1"
        },
        "alphabet_num_sep_with_underscore" : {
          "catenate_all" : "true",
          "split_on_case_change" : "false",
          "type" : "word_delimiter_graph",
          "type_table" : [
            "_ => ALPHA"
          ],
          "preserve_original" : "true"
        },
        "graph_synonyms1gram" : {
          "updateable" : "false",
          "type" : "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym1gram.txt",
          "lenient" : "true"
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : {
        "name_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "graph_synonyms",
            "alphabet_num_sep",
            "flatten_graph",
            "unique",
            "condition_shingle_filter"
          ],
          "char_filter" : [
            "arabic_letter_normalizer",
            "handle_punctuations"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "name_search_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "graph_synonyms",
            "alphabet_num_sep",
            "unique",
            "condition_shingle_filter"
          ],
          "char_filter" : [
            "arabic_letter_normalizer",
            "handle_punctuations"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "first_2gram" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "limit_2_token",
            "graph_synonyms2gram",
            "flatten_graph",
            "unique"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "first_3gram" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "limit_3_token",
            "graph_synonyms3gram",
            "flatten_graph",
            "unique"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "first_1gram" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "limit_1_token",
            "graph_synonyms1gram",
            "flatten_graph",
            "unique"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "first_3gram_search" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "limit_3_token",
            "graph_synonyms3gram"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "refined_name_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "graph_synonyms",
            "alphabet_num_sep_with_underscore",
            "flatten_graph",
            "unique",
            "condition_shingle_filter"
          ],
          "char_filter" : [
            "arabic_letter_normalizer",
            "handle_punctuations_no_underscore"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "first_2gram_search" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "limit_2_token",
            "graph_synonyms2gram"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "refined_name_search_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "graph_synonyms",
            "alphabet_num_sep_with_underscore",
            "unique",
            "condition_shingle_filter"
          ],
          "char_filter" : [
            "arabic_letter_normalizer",
            "handle_punctuations_no_underscore"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        },
        "first_1gram_search" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "decimal_digit",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "limit_1_token",
            "graph_synonyms1gram"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        }
      },
      "char_filter" : {
        "handle_punctuations_no_underscore" : {
          "type" : "mapping",
          "mappings" : [
            "'=>",
            "‌=> "
          ]
        },
        "arabic_letter_normalizer" : {
          "type" : "mapping",
          "mappings_path" : "analysis/arabic_char_replace.txt"
        },
        "handle_punctuations" : {
          "type" : "mapping",
          "mappings_path" : "analysis/punctuations_char_replace.txt"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas" : "1",
    "uuid" : "4C3fbpKGSzqpXRG-I-c_SA",
    "version" : {
      "created" : "7170099"
    }
  }
}
```

For example, look at `synonym3gram.txt` and `synonym.txt` above. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-with-synonyms.html#synonyms-store-synonyms-file) we should put these files on every node for Elasticsearch to pick them up. Since our Elasticsearch is a service (PAAS) and we don't have access to its deployment files, We are unable to put `synonym3gram.txt` and `synonym.txt` for example.

How can I replicate the same settings structure in our Kubernetes cluster? Is it possible to use S3 for synonym and stop words files?